# Can't play a youtube in an Android webview (API level 18+)

Tags: android, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api

I've done it all...

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

and this:

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and this:

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

and this won't play from a remote website:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" class="youtube-player" 
 type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-SHwpedtwxc" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

Just a black box in the middle of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "allowfullscreen" and it started working:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" class="youtube-player"     
type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-SHwpedtwxc" 
frameborder="0" autoplay></iframe>
```